Are locally free sheaves (mayn't be of finite rank) reflexive?
Suppose $X$ is a scheme, and $\mathcal{F}$ be a locally free sheaf (mayn't be of finite rank).
Definition of reflexive is given here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AVU
Note that in the definition of reflexive, they stacks project assumes $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent, and hence finite type. But for the definition of reflexive, we don't need $\mathcal{F}$ to be coherent.
I know if $\mathcal{F}$ be a locally free sheaf of finite rank, then it would be reflexive. But I don't know if this is true for any locally free sheaf. Any help would in proving or disapproving this would be appreciated.

If $X = \text{Spec } K$ then $F$ is just a $K$-vector space and you can check that (assuming the axiom of choice) $F$ is reflexive iff it's finite-dimensional.

The linked duplicate gives a counterexample in the case when $X$ is the spectrum of a field, modulo some translation.

@QiaochuYuan This resolves my question. Just have a follow through question. Are finite locally free sheaves reflexive? I think they should be. Same proof as locally free sheaves of finite rank should work.

@RamandeepSinghArora "They're the same picture."
